# Formatting a number string to add commas - c#

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I know this question has been answered many times before however, I'm convinced the code I have is correct but isn't working correctly.

```
string total = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
string test = string.Format("{0:N}", total);
lbl_totalValue.Text = test;
```

This code isn't adding the commas into my value like it desire it to.

Can anyone see why?

Comment: You are trying to format a *string*, not a number

Comment: `var total = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]; string test = string.Format("{0:N}", total);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you put

```
  string total = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

it means implicit `G` ("General") format string

```
  string total = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString("G");
```

Do not format *prematurely*:

```
  var total = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];         // Value from table
  string test = string.Format("{0:N}", total); // Format total with "N" format string
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to format a *string*. If the DataTable contains a number you can pass the format specifier to `ToString()`, eg

```
var test=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString("N");
```

Or store the contents in a local variable and use `String.Format` :

```
var total = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
string test = string.Format("{0:N}", total);
```

If the datatable contains a string though, you'd have to parse it to a numeric type first

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `string.Format` with a number type, instead of string. In this case, the variable `total` is a string, it must be a number.

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 overloads for the [Strig.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You are using this specific one: [Format(String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx) in which you pass a `String` value as argument of the second parameter. This is because you are using a string variable (`total`) to assign the value from the dataset in:

```
string total = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Besides you are using `.ToString()` to retrieve it as a `String`.

If you are using SQL Server as data source to your `ds` dataset and you are certain about the `SQL data type` then you can assign that value directly to a variable with the corresponding `C# type`. To put it in a different way, [SQL data types are mapped to C# data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). 
If you are not sure about the `C# data type` of `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]` then you could simply do the following:

```
Object total = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
string test = string.Format("{0:N}", total);
lbl_totalValue.Text = test;
```

And this way you literally use the `Format(String, Object)` overload of `String.Format`.